# How can I change flat rate shipping price when coupon is being applied on specific product?

Tags: woocommerce

How can I change flat rate shipping price when coupon is being applied on specific product?

As I am using the below code but not found any solution to get current coupon value.

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );

   function apply_matched_coupons() {
   global $woocommerce;

  echo $coupon_code = 'custom14'; // your coupon code here
  $code='custom';



      if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

      $the_coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );

     if (  $the_coupon->id ) {echo "here".$the_coupon->id;
       $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $code );

         } 
           }
```

Any help will be appriciated, thanks.